# Custom model metadata provider caching issue

Tags: caching, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-5.1, modelmetadataprovider

In order to allow us dynamic control over labels and error messages, we created a custom `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`. In a `Display` attribute we store the key in the `Name` property and using the custom `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` we substitute the key for a string value from our custom CMS. The problem is that we now have two sets of values. One for Web views and one for mobile views. At runtime we check if the client is on a mobile device and substitute the values accordingly.

After test running this setup I came across a strange issue. When the `AppDomain` is first created and the `Name` properties of the different data annotations are replaced with the string values, everything works fine. In debug, when I enter the custom `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` for a second time, I see the name properties already populated with the values I had substituted the previous run. This was strange to me, since it was my understanding that data annotation propeties could not be chnaged at runtime. It now seems like there is a model metadata cache happening somewhere. Since I based my custom solution on replacing the values each time the `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` is called upon, I would like to disable this caching, if possible.

For now I started using the `ShortName` property as my key storing property and I replace the `Name` property, and this way I can repopulate the strings on each run. But this was not the initial design and I don't have such a key store property for `ValidationAttributes`.

So is there a way to disable this cache? I don't need the cache for the sake of caching, since all CMS data is cached in memory in another layer anyway.

Comment: The same problem, all my error messages are cached and I still can't find the solution :-(

Comment: I'm having the same problem. And my solution is similar to yours: I just repopulate the errormessages on each request which is not the most efficient method.

Comment: same here, couldn't find anything that looked like caching in the base class though :( https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider.cs

Comment: Same issue I have also :(